# How To Update Database Using Primary Key

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a form that sends a update sql piece of code to my database.

The database consists of 1 table, which has 6 columns. They are, `key`, `download`, `link`, `version`, `name`, `fs_version`.

I've got key setup as a primary entry and I my form updates all the fields except for the key field and name field. It cannot update the name field as it doesn't have that information.

A generated SQL piece of code form the form looks like this:

```
UPDATE `mytable` SET `version`=2, `link`=44, `fs_version`=55, 
`download`=66, WHERE `key` = 1;
```

But I always get the error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `key` = 1' at line 1
```

What is it I can do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an extra comma right before `WHERE`, you don't need it. So just remove and everything will be fine

```
UPDATE `mytable`
   SET `version`=2, `link`=44, `fs_version`=55, `download`=66, WHERE `key` = 1
                                                             ^-----
```

Comment: @Ken Bloom: I don't agree adding backtick makes any sense for non-reserved names

Comment: I added them because they were in the original question. (You didn't see them because he didn't indent the code to get block code formatting, so they got interpreted as inline code formatting.) I added them to your answer to eliminate the syntax difference between his question and your answer, after I fixed his code formatting.

Comment: It's up to you to decide, but I'd really like it if you'd add the backticks back into the answer, now that you can see that they were there in the question.

Comment: @Ken Bloom: Oh my bad, sorry. I need glasses :-S

Comment: I'm sorry my edit comment was less than clear. I accidentally whacked the enter key in the middle of it.

Comment: @Ken Bloom: and I actually never read edit comments, not I will do :-)